# Multithreaded C++: force read from memory, bypassing cache

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching

I'm working on a personal hobby-time game engine and I'm working on a multithreaded batch executor. I was originally using a concurrent lockless queue and std::function all over the place to facilitate communication between the master and slave threads, but decided to scrap it in favor of a lighter-weight way of doing things that give me tight control over memory allocation:  function pointers and memory pools.

Anyway, I've run into a problem:

The function pointer, no matter what I try, is only getting read correctly by one thread while the others read a null pointer and thus fail an assert.

I'm fairly certain this is a problem with caching. I have confirmed that all threads have the same address for the pointer. I've tried declaring it as volatile, intptr_t, std::atomic, and tried all sorts of casting-fu and the threads all just seem to ignore it and continue reading their cached copies.

I've modeled the master and slave in a model checker to make sure the concurrency is good, and there is no livelock or deadlock (provided that the shared variables all synchronize correctly)

```
void Executor::operator() (int me) {
    while (true) {
        printf("Slave %d waiting.\n", me);
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(batch.ready_m);
            while(!batch.running) batch.ready.wait(lock);
            running_threads++;
        }
        printf("Slave %d running.\n", me);
        BatchFunc func = batch.func;
        assert(func != nullptr);

        int index;
        if (batch.store_values) {
            while ((index = batch.item.fetch_add(1)) < batch.n_items) {
                void* data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(batch.data_buffer + index * batch.item_size);
                func(batch.share_data, data);
            }
        }
        else {
            while ((index = batch.item.fetch_add(1)) < batch.n_items) {
                void** data = reinterpret_cast<void**>(batch.data_buffer + index * batch.item_size);
                func(batch.share_data, *data);
            }
        }

        // at least one thread finished, so make sure we won't loop back around
        batch.running = false;

        if (running_threads.fetch_sub(1) == 1) { // I am the last one
            batch.done = true; // therefore all threads are done
            batch.complete.notify_all();
        }
    }
}

void Executor::run_batch() {
    assert(!batch.running);
    if (batch.func == nullptr || batch.n_items == 0) return;

    batch.item.store(0);

    batch.running = true;
    batch.done = false;
    batch.ready.notify_all();

    printf("Master waiting.\n");
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(batch.complete_m);
        while (!batch.done) batch.complete.wait(lock);
    }
    printf("Master ready.\n");

    batch.func = nullptr;
    batch.n_items = 0;
}
```

`batch.func` is being set by another function

```
template<typename SharedT, typename ItemT>
void set_batch_job(void(*func)(const SharedT*, ItemT*), const SharedT& share_data, bool byValue = true) {
    static_assert(sizeof(SharedT) <= SHARED_DATA_MAXSIZE, "Shared data too large");
    static_assert(std::is_pod<SharedT>::value, "Shared data type must be POD");
    assert(std::is_pod<ItemT>::value || !byValue);
    assert(!batch.running);
    batch.func = reinterpret_cast<volatile BatchFunc>(func);
    memcpy(batch.share_data, (void*) &share_data, sizeof(SharedT));
    batch.store_values = byValue;
    if (byValue) {
        batch.item_size = sizeof(ItemT);
    }
    else { // store pointers instead of values
        batch.item_size = sizeof(ItemT*);
    }
    batch.n_items = 0;
}
```

and here is the struct (and typedef) that it's dealing with

```
typedef void(*BatchFunc)(const void*, void*);
struct JobBatch {
    volatile BatchFunc func;
    void* const share_data = operator new(SHARED_DATA_MAXSIZE);

    intptr_t const data_buffer = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(operator new (EXEC_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE));
    volatile size_t item_size;
    std::atomic<int> item; // Index into the data array
    volatile int n_items = 0;

    std::condition_variable complete; // slave -> master signal
    std::condition_variable ready;    // master -> slave signal
    std::mutex complete_m;
    std::mutex ready_m;

    bool store_values = false;

    volatile bool running = false; // there is work to do in the batch
    volatile bool done = false;    // there is no work left to do

    JobBatch();
} batch;
```

How do I make sure that all the necessary reads and writes to `batch.func` get synchronized properly between threads?

Just in case it matters: I'm using Visual Studio and compiling an x64 Debug Windows executable. Intel i5, Windows 10, 8GB RAM.

Comment: Why do you have multiple volatile things in the structure?

Comment: Might be a good idea to provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The excessiveness of volatile is pretty much my worrying that _other_ variables besides the function pointer are causing cache contention in overreaction to things not working as I expect them to.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, but writing concurrent data structures is one of the biggest challenges one can decide to take on and requires a lot of theoretical knowledge. You're better off using some existing libraries than trying to roll your own. Talking about "bypass cache" alone isa clear example that you haven't understood the c++ memory system and shouldn't try to do this.

Comment: @Beefster Even on a cursory glance I count at least two serious bugs and that's ignoring the use of volatile which is absolutely useless for concurrent programming in C++. Can you name all possible reorderings at every point in your program and why it won't cause a problem? "Reading from main memory" is a meaningless requirement. For one no modern CPU has such an instruction (ignoring SSE performance optimisations) and even if there were this would not be enough to be useful. You have to think about memory reorderings and visibility guarantees, not caches or main memory.

Comment: Sigh. I guess it's back to the heavyweight system I was using before. Thank God for Git.

Comment: Or switch to using mutexes. I have now learned the hard way that lockless programming is _hard_. **_Really hard_**

Answer (score 0):

Reading on the C++ memory model I maybe managed a solution:

- When done writing things that you want other threads to see, call `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)`.
- On the receiving thread(s), before reading shared data call `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)`.

In my case, release should be done immediately before waiting on a condition variable and acquire should be done immediately before using data written by other threads.

This ensures that the writes on one thread are seen by the others.

I still have a deadlock/livelock problem to sort out.

tl;dr: It's not exactly a cache thing: threads might not have their data in sync unless you enforce that with atomic memory fences.

Comment: Mutexes, semaphores, other locks do the memory fencing for you. If such locks have been used correctly then there is no need for additional memory fences.